# Is Normal a valid option for CSS Display value

Tags: css

Using Visual Studio autocomplete, it says that I can use normal as a valid value for display but when I use validator.w3.org, it says Normal is not valid. Is Normal valid or just Microsoft's value....

[image]

Chrome doesn't give it as an option when editing the css in the broswer.  If I don't use normal, parts of my website breaks, if I do, both work.

Comment: The nearest I can find was that `normal` was a proposed value of the abandoned `display-box` property to contrast with the `none` and `contents` values, which were later subsumed into the `display` property. But `normal` wasn't, and `display-box` was not part of the `display` shorthand property, so I don't think it was ever a valid value.

Comment: No. Use `display: block;` or `display; inherit;`.